# Add Tag Cloud to WowChemy theme

Tags: wowchemy

I am trying to add tags to the home page of my [website](https://www.ajitgoel.net/). I added the tag_cloud based on the documentation [here](https://wowchemy.com/docs/widget/tag-cloud/). I however do not see the tag_cloud added to my home page.

What could I be missing?

I had previously created a [github question](https://github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/issues/2498) for adding tags in my wowchemy site, but it was closed without comment.

**Example page where I have added Tag_cloud:**(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajitgoel/hugo-blog-theme/main/content/home/index.md)

```
---
# Homepage
type: widget_page
widget: tag_cloud
# Homepage is headless, other widget pages are not.
headless: true
content:
  # Choose the taxonomy from `config.yaml` to display (e.g. tags, categories)
  taxonomy: tags
  # Choose how many tags you would like to display (0 = all tags)
  count: 20
design:
  # Minimum and maximum font sizes (1.0 = 100%).
  font_size_min: 0.7
  font_size_max: 2.0
---
```

Comment: Hello Ajit. I think the point is you are going to have to code it. So, you're going to have to learn Hugo. That's the real answer. Then when you start down that path, then you'll have question more than well, this isn't really a question that is answerable other than by the doing the work. And then we can help...

Comment: Thank you @Rogelio for your input, documentation at https://wowchemy.com/docs/widget/tag-cloud/ says that I should be able to add the tag cloud by "placing the tags option in the front matter of your pages", which I did. Why do I have to code a "plugin" in "Go"? Can you please advise?

Comment: I assume you are coming from wordpress, and that's why you mention a plugin. So with Hugo - you have to move away from the endless plugins concept. I would say, you should then add some of your pages to the tag taxonomy and see if they show up. If not, learn Hugo and understand. Starting with the GettingStarted in the docs and code.

Comment: using the https://wowchemy.com/docs/content/taxonomy-pages/ documentation, I configured the content\tags and content\categories folders, but I still do not see the tag cloud on the home page.